# Should 'sound' tag be a synonym of 'noise'?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Should [sound](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound) (x4) tag be a synonym of [noise](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noise) (**x71**)?

Comment: I would be very careful with this. I don't think "sound" coming from airplane instrumentations (hypothetical question) is the same as "noise", since "noise" means "a sound, especially one that is loud or unpleasant or that causes disturbance." Those mistagged questions with "sound" probably need to be retagged with "noise" though.

Comment: @AndrewT. - makes sense, as in aural warnings.

Comment: @AndrewT I would think a more specific tag would be better there, like 'aural-warning'.

Comment: @Sanchises it's up to the community to decide, I'm not an expert in aviation :) but my point was, "sound" doesn't always mean "noise", so perhaps there are legit questions related to "sound" but not "noise" (or, there are none!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I don't see the need. They currently are not confused or misused, and making them synonym would remove flexibility.