# What tag to use for warning sounds (and lights)?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [sound](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound) was merged into [noise](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noise). I proposed the synonym 1.5 years ago: [Should 'sound' tag be a synonym of 'noise'?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3579/14897) The top-voted answer and comments there made a good case for **them being separate,** for example, [noise] doesn't make sense here: [What are the triggers of the MD-80's takeoff configuration warnings?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/64358/14897) But I could not take my vote back, and it went through a few hours ago.

(For that particular MD-80 post it's now showing as [sound] due to a known bug / mod edit.)

@Sanchises recommended in a comment to use [aural-warning](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aural-warning), but that leaves visual warnings out.

So, perhaps [warnings-cautions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warnings-cautions), in line with typical FCOM chapters? Or, [indicating-recording-systems](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indicating-recording-systems), in line with [ATA chapters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATA_100)?

Or something else? What are your thoughts?

Comment: Do you think this question should be re-tagged in line with this? https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/53532/what-did-the-gear-warning-horn-on-the-north-american-p-51-sound-like

Comment: @Notts90: Yep. There are some 40 others, but it's better to do 2 or 3 tops every 24h or so. I'll retag it now, and another that was asked today: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/72426/14897 Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest [cockpit-alerts](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cockpit-alerts).

[warnings](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warnings) might be confused with ATC warnings, FAA warning letters, or FCOM warnings that have nothing to do with sounds and lights designed to alert a pilot in the cockpit.

"Alerts" also include indications that aren't necessary "warnings", for example the C-chord when reaching within 150 feet of selected altitude.

Comment: Done: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cockpit-alerts -- thanks